# python slice() function vs slice notation - How to handle empty values in slice()?

Tags: python

The docs cover 3 usages of the [slice()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=slice#slice) object:

- `obj[:stop]` = `obj[slice(stop)]`
- `obj[start:stop]` = `obj[slice(start, stop)]`
- `obj[start:stop:step]`  =  `obj[slice(start, stop, step)]`

But how to do this when I don't know the length of the object in advance? Setting `stop` to a very high value, like `2E32-1`?

- `obj[start:]` =  `obj[slice(start, 2E32-1)]`?
- `obj[:]` =  `obj[slice(2E32-1)]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the `stop` argument to `None` to continue indefinitely.

```
obj = [1, 2, 3, 4]

obj[2:] == obj[slice(2, None)]
# == [3, 4]

obj[:] == obj[slice(None, None)]
# == [1, 2, 3, 4]

obj[::2] == obj[slice(None, None, 2)]
# == [1, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use Python's [**`slice()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) function with all the capabilities provided by the *slice notation*. Internally, both `slice()` function and the slice notation uses the [**`slice`**](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-slice) object.

In your *slice notation* `your_list[start:stop:step]`, where you pass empty value, you may get the equivalent `slice` function `slice(start, stop, step)` via passing that value as `None`. For example:

- **usage of only `start` with empty `end`**

  ```
  >>> my_list = list(range(10))  # for demonstration purpose

  # start: `5`
  # end: empty - meaning end of the list
  >>> my_list[5:]
  [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

  # use `end` as `None`
  >>> my_list[slice(5, None)]  
  [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
  ```
- **usage of only `end` with empty `start`**

  ```
  >>> my_list[:5]
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

  >>> my_list[slice(5)]
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
  # OR
  >>> my_list[slice(None, 5)]
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
  ```
- **both `start` and `end` as empty** (copy of list)

  ```
  >>> my_list[:]
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

  >>> my_list[slice(None, None)]
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
  ```

Few more example:

```
# with both `start` and `end`
>>> my_list[2:5]
[2, 3, 4]
>>> my_list[slice(2, 5)]
[2, 3, 4]

# with `start`, `end` and `step`
>>> my_list[2:5:3]
[2]
>>> my_list[slice(2, 5, 3)]
[2]

# To reverse list
#     with empty `start` and `end`, and `step` as `-1`
>>> my_list[::-1]
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
>>> my_list[slice(None, None, -1)]
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```